# In Caprica, what caused the deterioration in friendship between Joseph Adama and Gautreau?

Tags: plot-explanation, caprica

In [Caprica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprica), the friendship between Joseph, Sam Adama, and Gautreau deteriorates to the point that Gautreau orders a hit them.  What caused this deterioration?  Did they disobey Gautreau at some point?

Comment: You might like to add some context here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First - Historic Context:**

> The Adamas are a Tauron family who live in Caprica City. They have
>   strong connections to their homeworld, other local Taurons, and to the
>   Tauron-based criminal organization, **Ha'la'tha.**
>
> William Adama Sr. and Isabelle Adama are poor farmers on the planet,
>   Tauron. They have two sons, Joseph and Sam. They are members of a
>   Tauron resistance group called the Ha'la'tha. The Ha'la'tha fights the
>   corrupt Tauron government, its military arm, the Heraclides, and their
>   murder squads, the Heracs.
>
> The Adamas are a Tauron family who live in Caprica City. They have
>   strong connections to their homeworld, other local Taurons, and to the
>   Tauron-based criminal organization, Ha'la'tha.
>
> W**illiam Adama Sr. and Isabelle Adama are poor farmers on the planet,
>   Tauron. They have two sons, Joseph and Sam. They are members of a
>   Tauron resistance group called the Ha'la'tha.** The Ha'la'tha fights the
>   corrupt Tauron government, its military arm, the Heraclides, and their
>   murder squads, the Heracs.
>
> The brothers Joseph and Sam Adama immigrate to Caprica as children
>   after they are orphaned in the Tauron Civil War (12YR - 14YR). They
>   move to Caprica City. **Sam and Joseph join the Ha'la'tha as children.
>   The boss of the Caprican Ha'la'tha, the Guatrau, takes them under his
>   wing. By this time the Ha'la'tha has become an organized crime
>   organization.** ("Pilot")
>
> While growing up on Caprica, **Sam unsuccessfully hits on the guys in
>   Little Tauron, the Tauron enclave in Caprica City. He grows up to
>   become a Ha'la'tha enforcer**. Sam marries a non-Tauron by the name of
>   Larry. They do not have children because of the dangerous nature of
>   Sam's job with the Ha'la'tha. Their marriage is a happy one.

**The Story in the first season of Caprica:**

> **In order to regain control of his company from Tomas Vergis, Daniel
>   Graystone makes a deal with the Guatrau for funding to develop the
>   Resurrection Program and "influence" to convince the board to oust
>   Vergis.** The Guatrau tells Joseph Adama to represent his interests at
>   Graystone. Joseph begins to object, but the Guatrau tells him this is
>   an honor. ("Unvanquished")
>
> The Guatrau's shell company, Obolus Inc., purchases Graystone
>   Industries. **Daniel hopes that the Guatrau will let him remain in
>   control of the company. However, the Gautrau attends a meeting at
>   which Cyrus Xander demonstrates a proposed commercial for the
>   Resurrection Program.** Daniel wants the commercial scrubbed, but the
>   Guatrau overrules him. ("Unvanquished") ("False Labor") ("Dirteaters")
>
> As Joseph and Sam Adama are about to be promoted in the Ha'la'tha, the
>   Guatrau tells the story of how they met. The Adama brothers had
>   immigrated to Caprica as orphans. Sam tried to pick his pocket. Right
>   then he knew that Sam had the stones to be one of them. The Guatrau
>   noticed Joseph's eyes. He was always calculating something. They are
>   like sons to him. ("Dirteaters")
>
> His daughter, Fidelia, is released from prison. **She goes to Graystone
>   Industries to get caught up on the family business. She investigates
>   the books and finds discrepancies about some missing robots. She has
>   discovered Joseph's and Sam's secret operation to funnel robots to the
>   resistance on Tauron.** ("The Heavens Will Rise")
>
> She brings this evidence to her father, but he refuses to listen to
>   her. He says the Adama brothers are like sons to him and they would
>   not do this. She tells him she is his actual daughter and he trusts
>   her to tell him what others are afraid to tell him, and what he cannot
>   face himself. **She says the Adamas' robot operation to Tauron will be
>   popular and will make him look bad. He tells her to make it quick and
>   painless.** ("Here Be Dragons") http://caprica.wikia.com/wiki/Guatrau

So ultimately, because of the secret operation of sending the robots to Tuaron, the Guatrau sees this as a betrayal, because it will make him look bad, not caring for the Tauron people that he allegedly says he cares for.

Comment: No worries! Glad to help. :)